# Form submission trigger doesn´t run right function

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a sheet with an integrated form, when I fill the form it should runs macro "myFunction". Its basicly takes new data from sheet "respostas do formulário" and writes it on last empty row of sheet "Reservas".
Although its writing data incorrectly on the first row of sheet "Reservas".
When I run "myFunction" macro direcly from sheet it works perfectly, but when using form submission trigger doesn´t.
any help?
Function code:

```
   function myFunction() {
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  /** Seleciona o começo dos nomes para ir na última linha em branco */
  spreadsheet.getRange('B4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, -1).activate();
  /** Vai pra Planilha de Respostas e organiza para a última reserva ficar na linha 2 */
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), false);
  /** Copiar a Data na planilha de respostas e cola na planilha de reservas */
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!B2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy DDD');
  /** Copiar o Nome Cliente na planilha de respostas e cola na planilha de reservas */
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!C2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  /** Copiar o telefone na planilha de respostas e cola na planilha de reservas */
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!D2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 2).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!E2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!F2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!G2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!H2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!I2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 17).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!J2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!K2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -11).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!L2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!M2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!N2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!O2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!P2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 4).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 13).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!T2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -3).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!U2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!V2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!W2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 6).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!X2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!Y2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Respostas ao formulário 1\'!Z2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  /** Filtra planilha de reservas pelo nome e depois pela data tava linha 1276*/
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -34).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), true);
   /** retira filtro da planilha de respostas */
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reservas'), true);
};
```

Kind Regards,
André

Comment: Hi ! Are you setting your function to trigger with an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)? More precisely, have you tried it with a ```Formsubmit``` [trgger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)? If that is the case, if you go to your [executions panel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard#manage_executions) is your trigger getting any errors?

Comment: Tks for helping, No, Its not an installable trigger,  I used a trigger from the button "add trigger". It doesnt have any errors at executions panel. that's why i have no idea why it doesn't work.
Trigger configuration are:
Choose the function to be performed: myFunction
Deployment to be performed: test
Select the event source: from spreadsheet
Select the type of event: when submitting the form

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I changed all the code, it worked but trigger is executing the function 3x per submit! There´s a way to make a "run once" trigger?

Comment: used the "Utilities.sleep(2000);" at the beginning and it worked fine. Tks.

Comment: Hi ! Yes, that is indeed a installable trigger. The behaviour you are experiencing of triggering several times when you submit the form is a known issue, please check [this bug report comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124283798#comment19) for more information regarding its workarounds. If you managed to solve your question please submit an answer to your post so that other users with similar problems can easily find your solution. Thanks ! :D